# При выборе начального пунка меню в навигации информация дублируется

Tags: kotlin, navigation, навигация, дублирование

Начал разрабатывать приложение с BottomNavigationView, сделал 3 фрагмента, выбрал начальный элемент меню. Но когда возвращаешься на данный фрагмент информация там дублируется. Просьба помочь понять почему это вообще происходит и как это исправить.

Хостовый активити:

```
import androidx.activity.viewModels


import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.example.firstapp.Flags

import com.example.firstapp.R
import com.example.firstapp.databinding.ActivityTestNavBinding

class TestNavActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding:ActivityTestNavBinding
    private val flag: Flags by viewModels()
    private lateinit var navController:NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityTestNavBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        Log.d("MyLog","Активити Нав создан")
        navController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
        Log.d("MyLog","Контроллер определен")
        flag.alreadyExistModule.value = true

    }
}
```

Код фрагмента:

```
package com.example.firstapp.Fragments


import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.firstapp.Adapter.ModulesAdapter
import com.example.firstapp.Flags
import com.example.firstapp.ModulesData
import com.example.firstapp.R
import com.example.firstapp.databinding.FragmentModuleBinding


class ModuleFrag : Fragment(), ModulesAdapter.Listener {
    lateinit var binding: FragmentModuleBinding
    private val adapter = ModulesAdapter(this)
    private val flags: Flags by activityViewModels()
    private val ImIdList = listOf(
        R.drawable.plug1,
        R.drawable.plug2,
        R.drawable.plug3,
        R.drawable.plug4,
        R.drawable.plug5,
    )

    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentModuleBinding.inflate(inflater)
        Log.d("MyLog","Запуск вью фрагмента ModuleFrag  ${flags.alreadyExistModule.value}")
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d("MyLog","Фрагмент вью создан ModuleFrag  ${flags.alreadyExistModule.value}")
        init()
    }
    
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() = ModuleFrag()
    }

    private fun init(){
            val modTitles = resources.getStringArray(R.array.ModTitle)
            val modDesc = resources.getStringArray(R.array.ModDesc)
            binding.apply {
                rcycModules.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                rcycModules.adapter = adapter
                for (index in 0..modTitles.size - 1) {
                    val module = ModulesData(
                        ImIdList[index],
                        modTitles[index],
                        modDesc[index],
                        index
                    )
                    adapter.addModule(module)
                }
            }
    }

    
    override fun onClick(module: ModulesData) {

        }
    }
```

Код адаптера для RecyclerView:

```
package com.example.firstapp.Adapter

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.firstapp.ModulesData
import com.example.firstapp.R
import com.example.firstapp.databinding.ModuleItemBinding

class ModulesAdapter(val listener: Listener): RecyclerView.Adapter<ModulesAdapter.ModulesHolder>() {
    val moduleList = ArrayList<ModulesData>()
    class ModulesHolder(item: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) {

        val binding = ModuleItemBinding.bind(item)
        fun bind(module: ModulesData, listener: Listener) = with(binding){
            imModule.setImageResource(module.ImgId)
            txtMainTitle.text = module.Title
            txtDesc.text = module.Subtitle
            btMain.setOnClickListener{
                listener.onClick(module)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ModulesHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.module_item, parent, false)
        return ModulesHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return moduleList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ModulesHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(moduleList[position], listener)
    }

    fun addModule(module: ModulesData){
        moduleList.add(module)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    interface Listener{
        fun onClick(module: ModulesData)
    }
}
```

Я пробовал поставить флаг, чтобы при заходе в init() флаг принимал значение true и затем, чтобы в данный метод больше не заходить, но в таком случае RecyclerView вообще ничего не рисует.

Разметка фрагмента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    tools:context=".Fragments.ModuleFrag">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rcycModules"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что у Фрагментов другой Жизненный Цикл, в отличии от Активити.

**Активити.**

---

У вас есть Активити-1, и вы поверх него открываете новое Активити-2.
Активити-1 уходит в состояние onPause. Когда вы возвращаетесь на него, оно переходит в состояние onResume.
Все вьюшки уже созданы, а логика, которую обычно пишут в onCreate, уже инициализирована.

**Фрагмент.**

---

Есть Фрагменте-1, поверх открывает Фрагмент-2.
И вот тут Фрагмент-1 сначала onPause, onStop, onDestroyView.
А когда возвращаетесь на него, но он опять выполняет onViewCreate и тд.
В момент, когда Фрагмента-1 находится в бэкстеге, все его вью уничтожаются (должны уничтожаться! если не уничтожены - это утечка памяти). Это касается и адаптеров для РесайклВью.

**Вывод:**

---

чтобы код работал правильно (без дублирования) и без утечки памяти (у вас адаптер переживает весь ЖЦ Фрагмента), вам надо код инициализации адаптера перенести в метод onViewCreated

Comment: Спасибо за ваш подробный ответ. И если я вас правильно понял, я должен всю функцию init() перенести в метод фрагмента onViewCreated: я все так и сделал, но информация все равно дублируется . Или я сделал что-то не так?

Comment: private val adapter = ModulesAdapter(this) тоже перенестие в onViewCreated

Comment: Боже мой, я не знаю как выразить вам свою благодарность, все заработало, спасибо!